# python argparse passing a delimited list

Tags: python, argparse

With the following:

```
parser.add_argument("-l", "--library", type=str, nargs="*", dest="scanLibrary")
```

There are going to be cases where the list of names passed may contain spaces. argparse is breaking the list up on whitespace so

```
mything.py -l test of foo, game of bar, How I foo bar your mother
```

nets me:

```
scanLibrary=['test', 'of', 'foo,', 'game', 'of', 'bar,', 'How', 'I', 'foo', 'bar', 'your', 'mother']
```

So how do I get argeparse to use a delimiter of my choosing?

Update:
Based on advice from Martijn Pieters, I made the following change:

```
parser.add_argument("-l", "--library", type=str, nargs="*", dest="scanLibrary")
print args.scanLibrary
print args.scanLibrary[0].split(',')
```

Which gave a result of:

```
mything.py -l "test of foo, game of bar, How I foo bar your mother"
['test of foo, game of bar, How I foo bar your mother']
['test of foo', ' game of bar', ' How I foo bar your mother']
```

I can clean up the leading space easy enough. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It is the *shell* that does the parsing here; it passes in the arguments to the process as a parsed list.

To prevent this, quote your argument:

```
mything.py -l "test of foo, game of bar, How I foo bar your mother"
```

Comment: Well that will require the user to remember to do that and an update to the help text, but thats no big deal. See my edit above for how this advice became my solution.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, an even better way to accomplish this, is to use a lambda function. This way you don't have to post-process your list, which keeps your code clean. You can do this neat little trick as follows:

```
# mything.py -l test of foo, game of bar, How I foo bar your mother

parser.add_argument("-l",
                    "--library",
                    type=lambda s: [i for i in s.split(',')],
                    dest="scanLibrary")

print(args.scanLibrary)

# ['test of foo', 'game of bar', 'How I foo bar your mother']
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on your question because of the 50 reps. I just wanted to say that you can use:

```
'   some string '.strip()
```

To get:

```
'some string'
```

Comment: That is ultimately what happened to each item and it has been running pretty steadily ever since. Thanks for adding this so the solution looks more complete to future searchers.